# up and down scroll with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to put together following codes but doesn't work. when i down scroll, page up button appears and when i click it, scroll is to be top of page. When i up the scroll to top of page, page down button appears and when i click it, it does same action with page up scroll.

```js
    var amountScrolledTop = 200;
    var amountScrolledDown = 50;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
     if ( $(window).scrollTop() > amountScrolledTop ) {
      $('a.back-to-top').fadeIn('slow');
     } else {
      $('a.back-to-top').fadeOut('slow');
     }
     if ( $(window).scrollTop() < amountScrolledDown ) {
      $('a.down1').fadeIn('slow');
     } else {
      $('a.down1').fadeOut('slow');
     }
    });

    $('a.back-to-top').click(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
     }, 'slow');
     return false;
    });

    $('a.down1').click(function() {
     var objDiv = document.getElementById("mid");
     objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
    });
```

```css
.down1{
     width: 60px;
     height: 60px;
     text-indent: -9999px;
     position: fixed;
     z-index: 999;
     right: 60px;
     top: 80px;
     background: url("../img/simple_icons/downArrow.png") no-repeat center 43%;
    }
    .back-to-top{
     display: none;
     width: 60px;
     height: 60px;
     text-indent: -9999px;
     position: fixed;
     z-index: 999;
     right: 20px;
     bottom: 20px;
     background: url("../img/simple_icons/upArrow.png") no-repeat center 43%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
     <a href="#" class="down1" id="down1">Down to</a>
        <a href="#" class="back-to-top" id="back-to-top">Back to Top</a>
        .
        .
        .
        <div class="mid"></div>
</body>
```

Page down button always up the scroll to top of page. Even i erase all the javascript code.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Try setting display none after fadeout...

Comment: what is the problem you are facing exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you were looking for, I put some comments on the code to describe the modifications I made.

```js
var amountScrolledTop = 200;
var amountScrolledDown = 50;

$(window).scroll(function() {

  if ( $(window).scrollTop() > amountScrolledTop ) {
    $('a.back-to-top').fadeIn('slow');
  } else {
    $('a.back-to-top').fadeOut('slow');
  }

  if ( $(window).scrollTop() < amountScrolledDown ) {
    $('a.down1').fadeIn('slow');
  } else {
    $('a.down1').fadeOut('slow');
  }
});

$('a.back-to-top').click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 'slow');
  return false;
});

$('a.down1').click(function(e) {
  
  //you have to prevent the default action of the link (the default going to the top because of href="#" even if there is no javascript)
  e.preventDefault();
  
  //objDiv used to be "null" because it was defined by class not id in html
  var objDiv = document.getElementById("mid");
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: objDiv.scrollHeight
  }, 'slow');
});
```

```css
.down1{
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  right: 60px;
  top: 80px;
  background: url("../img/simple_icons/downArrow.png") no-repeat center 43%;
}
.back-to-top{
  display: none;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background: url("../img/simple_icons/upArrow.png") no-repeat center 43%;
}
#mid {
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="down1" id="down1">Down to</a>
<a href="#" class="back-to-top" id="back-to-top">Back to Top</a>
<!-- it was class="mid" -->
<div id="mid"></div>
```